# Android: DrawerLayout with content view with two fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, drawerlayout

I'm creating the layout for a tablet and I have a `DrawerLayout`, which has a `Fragment` on the left menu (so the drawer) and should have two fragments as main content.

The way I'm doing it is the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="3"/>

    <View
        android:id="@+id/right_card_group_divider"
        android:layout_width="1dip"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/grey_line_bg"/>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/menu_frame_two"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1.3"/>
</LinearLayout>

<!-- The navigation drawer -->
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/menu_frame"
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Nevertheless, I notice that if I manually hide the "menu_frame_two", the `DrawerLayout` works perfectly, but if that `Fragment` isn't hidden, then when opening the `DrawerLayout` nothing appears on the screen: it gets darker, just like if the drawer has been opened.

Is there any reason why the left drawer menu isn't showing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `menu_frame_two` FrameLayout seems coming over the `menu_frame` Navigation Drawer. So navigation drawer is not visible that time

Solution :

- Use single `FrameLayout` and add all elemets of **main content screen** inside it

> ```
>  <FrameLayout android:id = "@+id/content_frame"         
>         android:layout_width="match_parent"
>         android:layout_height="match_parent" >
>    <FrameLayout
>     android:id="@+id/content_frame_inside"
>     android:layout_width="0dp"
>     android:layout_height="match_parent"
>     android:layout_weight="3"/>
>
> <View
>     android:id="@+id/right_card_group_divider"
>     android:layout_width="1dip"
>     android:layout_height="match_parent"
>     android:background="@drawable/grey_line_bg"/>
>
> <FrameLayout
>     android:id="@+id/menu_frame_two"
>     android:layout_width="0dp"
>     android:layout_height="match_parent"
>     android:layout_weight="1.3"/>
> </FrameLayout>
> ```

Reason :

- As per [Documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html) there should be one `content_frame` with height and width equal to `match_parent`